# JQuery - Adicionar atributo HTML em um elemento específico

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Estou tentando acessar um input específico através do seu ID para adicionar um atributo. Quero adicionar `pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric"`

```
<label class="prefixo"><input type="number" class="fitext freight-zip-box" id="txtCep" name="txtCep" value="" placeholder="CEP"></label>
```

Estou usando

```
$('#txtCep').attr('pattern', '[0-9]*');
$('#txtCep').attr('inputmode', 'numeric*');
```

Contudo, só consigo adicionar esses atributos se eu não utilizar nenhum seletor CSS. Somente com  `$('input')` dá certo porém, só preciso que um determinado elemento input seja atingido e não todos.
Já tentei pelo ID, pela classe e nada funciona.

Aqui está o código do input para digitar o CEP:

```
<div class="shipping-box"><p id="popupCalculoFreteWrapper" class="frete"><a onclick="ShippingValue();" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Calcule o valor do frete e prazo de entrega para a sua região" class="shipping-value">Calcule o valor do frete e prazo de entrega para a sua região</a></p><div id="calculoFrete" seller="1" produtocorrente="5224" skucorrente="5248"><div class="contentWrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <h1><a target="_parent" href="/" id="ctl00_lnkHome">motoatacado</a></h1>
        <h2>Digite seu CEP</h2>
        <div class="close"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="bt btn-thickbox" title="Fechar" id="lnkFechar1">Fechar</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="ctl00_Conteudo_upnlContent">
        <input type="hidden" name="CEPObrigatorio" id="CEPObrigatorio" value="O CEP deve ser informado.">
        <input type="hidden" name="CEPInvalido" id="CEPInvalido" value="CEP inválido.">
        <input type="hidden" name="ProdutoQuantidadeObrigatorio" id="ProdutoQuantidadeObrigatorio" value="É necessário informar a quantidade do mesmo Produto.">

        <input type="hidden" id="StrCountry" value="BRA">

        <div class="content">
            <div style="display: none;" class="aviso-erro" id="ctl00_Conteudo_lblErro">
                <div style="color: Red; display: none;" id="ctl00_Conteudo_vldSummary"></div>
            </div>
            <fieldset>
                <label class="prefixo"><input type="number" class="fitext freight-zip-box" id="txtCep" name="txtCep" value="" placeholder="CEP"></label>
                <div class="quantity"><input type="text" name="quantity" value="1"></div>
                <span class="frete-calcular btBordas btBordasInput">
                    <input type="hidden" id="stockKeepingUnitId" name="stockKeepingUnitId" value="5248">
                    <input type="button" class="bt freight-btn" title="OK" id="btnFreteSimulacao" value="Calcular" name="btnFreteSimulacao">
                    <span class="rdbd bdl"></span>
                    <span class="rdbd bdr"></span>
                </span>
                <span style="color: Red; display: none;" id="RegularExpressionValidator1"></span>
                <span style="color: Red; display: none;" id="RegularExpressionValidator2"></span>
                <span class="cep-busca"><a title="Não sei meu CEP" class="bt lnkExterno" target="_blank" href="http://www.buscacep.correios.com.br/sistemas/buscacep/">Não sei meu CEP</a></span>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="freight-values" style="display: none"></div>
            <span style="color: Red; display: none;" id="reqCep1"></span><span style="color: Red; display: none;" id="reqCep2"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="close"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="bt btn-thickbox" title="Fechar" id="lnkFechar2">Fechar</a></div>
    </div>
</div></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
                             $(document).ready( function(){
                                 ShippingValue();
                             });
                        </script></div>
```

Muito obrigado pela força!

Comment: Mas seu código está funcionando, ele pega o input de ID id="txtCep" e coloca os atributos certinho. qual é o problema?

Comment: Deveria funcionar. Vai no console e executa `$("#txtCep").length`... se retornar algo diferente de `1` pode ser o indício do problema.

Comment: Hugocsl Ocorre que, ele não está pegando o input com ID. Só dá certo se eu não colocar o ID e sim 'input'.

Comment: Tenta com `$('input[name="txtCep"]')` ou apenas `$('[name="txtCep"]')`

Comment: @Sam, não resolveu, nenhuma das duas formas :( Eu executei $("#txtCep").length e deu 1.

Comment: Numa tentativa de adivinhar, que só da para adivinhar com o que você colocou na pergunta, vou adivinhar que você tem id's repetidos na sua página, provavelmente esse mesmo `id` de `txtCep` deve estar repetido

Comment: @Isac eu não encontrei txtCep repetido. Falo assim porque o projeto não é meu, estou apenas modificando como solicitado. Além do mais, eu tentei utilizar também label.prefixo input,. fitext, .freight-zip-box. Procurei deixar a pergunta o mais enxuta possível. Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: @AntonioPina Certo, mas a questão aqui é que o código na pergunta funciona. Experimente criar uma página vazia com apenas o que colocou na pergunta e a referência ao JQuery e verá que funciona. Logo o problema está noutras coisas que você não mostra aqui e por consequência é nos impossível de ajudar. ID's repetidos é apenas um dos problemas comuns, mas naturalmente não quer dizer que seja esse, mas sem ver o resto do código é meramente tentativa de adivinhar.

Comment: @Isac Eu coloquei mas código. Será que ajuda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem-vindo ao SOpt. Experimente colocar um atributo no seu elemento do tipo data: `data-add`, com o ID que vc quer como parâmetro, depois só pegar pela ID:

**HTML:**

```
<label class="prefixo"><input data-add="1" type="number" class="fitext freight-zip-box" id="txtCep" name="txtCep" value="" placeholder="CEP"></label>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() {
   $('input[data-add="1"]')
    .attr('pattern', '[0-9]*')
    .attr('inputmode', 'numeric*');
});
```

Também pode fazer através de um método:

```
function setValidation(id) {
    $('[data-add="'+id+'"]')
        .attr('pattern', '[0-9]*')
        .attr('inputmode', 'numeric*');
} 
setValidation(1);
```

Comment: Boa tarde @Ivan, resolvi o problema. O que estava pegando é que eu estava trabalhando em um js errado. Trata-se de uma loja virtual, que trabalha com componentes. Eu encontrei o componente e apliquei o código simples mesmo `$('.prefixo input').attr('pattern', '[0-9]*').attr('inputmode', 'numeric*');`. Muito obrigado pela força!

Comment: Blz, que bom que resolveu. Precisando estamos por aqui.